# OpenERP 7 webservices support for Java?

Tags: web-services, odoo, json-rpc, java

I've been doing a lot of research for the past few days but it seems I can't arrive with the right answers. And most of the resources are scarce.

Here are my questions, hope you could help me answer it. These questions are all related to Java. On how to access OpenERP 7 data.

Does OpenERP 7 supports RESTFUL and JSON-RPC for Java?

How can we update information and prices for products (in the POS module?)

How we can do a bulk export of all products and prices, without pulling the data one product at a time?

Thank you very much.

-R

Answer (score 1):

There are already available doc for Android app and android internally use `Java` So may be this can help you

### [OpenERP Mobile Framework Doc](http://mobile.openerp.co.in/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes openerp support JSON-RPC

from here you can get information

http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/web/rpc/

Answer (score 0):

I've done a simple example using json-rpc on android with [android-json-rpc api](https://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/), to fetch partners through http and https (using self-signed certificate) : https://bitbucket.org/petrus-v/openerpconnection

I haven't found good documentation about openerp low-level json-rpc api, my way was to understand request done with openERP client using any good browser's debbuger.

Hope it's help

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official doc website from [**here**](https://doc.openerp.com/6.1/developer/12_api/#python)

Answer (score 0):

you could always look at wrapper libs for xml-rpc like [OERPLib](http://pythonhosted.org/OERPLib/) and port them to java